# Manually loading associations in EF model

Tags: entity-framework-4

I need to use parameterized table-valued functions to retrieve the data for an association (the TVFs abstract the actual database tables), but would like to use all the good stuff provided by the EF. So looking at the generated Navigation Property code from the EDMX, I see that the RelationshipManager wraps the population etc. of the association.

So my question: can I retrieve the results I need from the DB (via the TVFs) and attach them to the context before the generated calls to the RelationshipManager, and also stop the RM itself from accessing the database?

Answer (score 0):

EF4 does not support TVF. TVFs are available only in .NET 4.5 where you can use them in Linq-to-entities queries. .NET 4.5 also by default uses POCO entities which are now strongly recommended where `RelationshipManager` is not used inside the entity (except dynamic proxies for lazy loading).

Comment: I think it would be fairer to say that TVFs have limited report in 4.0.  You can certainly import TVFs by manually editing the EDMX XML, and call them from the context.